# Python: split hard coded path

Tags: python

I need to split a path up in python and then remove the last two levels.

Here is an example, the path I want to parse. I want to parse it to level 6.

```
C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8
```

Below is what I want the output to be. Currently, I can only go one level up.

```
C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\
```

---

```
a ="C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8"
split_path=os.path.split(a)
print split_path
```

Output:

```
 ('C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7','level8')
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I.e. do you always want to get to level6, or always remove the last two levels?

Comment: I want to always remove the last two levels

Comment: Appending `/../..` to your path works. `C:/some/deep/path/../` is equivalent to `C:/some/deep/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `split` function twice:

```
os.path.split(os.path.split(a)[0])[0]
```

This works since `os.path.split()` returns a tuple with two items, head and tail, and by taking `[0]` of that we'll get the head. Then just split again and take the first item again with `[0]`.

Or join your path with the parent directory twice:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(a, '..', '..'))
```

You can easily create a function that will step back as many steps as you want:

```
def path_split(path, steps):
    for i in range(steps + 1):
        path = os.path.split(path)[0]
    return path
```

So

```
>>> path_split("C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8", 2)
"C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\"
```

Answer (score 4):

Split the path into all its parts, then join all the parts, except the last two.

```
import os

seperator = os.path.sep
parts = string.split(seperator)
output = os.path.join(*parts[0:-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.split(path)` gives the whole path except the lastone, and the last one in a tuple. So if you want to remove the last two,

```
os.path.split(os.path.split(your_path)[0])[0]
```