# how to parse and append a word in Python

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8\test.txt
```

above is the example
i need to change test.txt to test1.txt
and move it up a level to a new directory. My problem is I dont know how to grab test.txt and append or concatenate 1 to it and put it back together.I kind of need help with this part.And i dont know how to change level 7 to test.
Below is what I want:

```
wanted output:C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\test\test1.txt


a ="C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8\test.txt"

split_path=os.path.split(a)

print split_path

test1 = os.path.splitext(a)

print test1
```

**Output:**

```
 ('C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7','test.txt')
```

('C:\Users\Me\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7\level8\test','.txt')

Comment: Use `a.split(os.pathsep)` instead of `os.path.split(a)`.

Comment: Please format your code as code and give us a complete example of what you have tried. If your only attempt is one call to path.spit most people here wont help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What's going on in Florida?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711168/python-split-hard-coded-path/35711280#35711280)

Split the path into parts. Manipulate the individual parts.

```
 import os

 seperator = os.path.sep
 parts = string.split(seperator)
 output =  os.path.join(*parts[0:-2], 'schema_directory', 'testschema.json')
```

That's assuming that when you say you want to "move it up a level to a new directory" you mean that you want the directory to be in level 7, not level 6 like you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

The following building blocks should give you what you are looking for.

[os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.rename) from standard library will move/rename in a single call. Here is an example:

```
import os

os.rename('testdir1\\oldname.txt', 'testdir2\\newname.txt')
```

If you want to find a path to a file, you can use [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)

```
import os

print(os.path.abspath('testdir2\\newname.txt'))
```

If you want just the directory name without the file name, you can use [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
>>> os.path.dirname('C:\\dir1\dir2\\testdir2\\newname.txt'))
>>> C:\dir1\dir2\testdir2
```

Comment: What happened to the anwser where he wrote a function you pass level and path

Comment: @Testerflorida, Batman's answer is still there. Try refreshing the page.